# Why buttons has the same size on multiple screens (Android 1.6+)?

Tags: android, layout, textview, density-independent-pixel

Please help me with one problem. When I change min sdk version from 3 (Android 1.5) to 4 (1.6) or higher, all buttons and textviews have the same size on multiple screens although I use dp and sp units. Why might this be?

Simple example (main.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:text="OK"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Screenshot from Google Nexus 7:**
http://s019.radikal.ru/i601/1312/fd/e769f6e3a690.png

**Screenshot from Sony Ericsson Xperia Play:**
http://s019.radikal.ru/i600/1312/9d/6b3f580e7503.png

Comment: Put atleast two screens of diff. resolution

Comment: I added 2 screenshots

Comment: see my posted answer below

Comment: Thank you so much, but...is there any easier way to do it? for example, programmatically calculate size of buttons depending on screen density?

Comment: I tried to do like this: `final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int dip = (int) (55 * scale);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(dip, dip, 0);
        button.setLayoutParams(lp); ` but button has the same size pn both devices. So it's not work

Comment: Maybe I can resize button using getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `dimen.xml` for following folder as per your requirement:

1. `values`
2. `values-hdpi`
3. `values-ldpi`
4. `values-mdpi`
5. `values-sw600dp`
6. `values-sw720dp-land` etc...

and code for that `dimen.xml` and give `xxxdp` as you want:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="button_width">300dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="button_height">300dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

then after you `xml` file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:text="OK"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

FOR PROGRAMMATICALLY:

This also works:

```
getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

This will give you:

- 0.75 - ldpi
- 1.0 - mdpi
- 1.5 - hdpi
- 2.0 - xhdpi
- 3.0 - xxhdpi
- 4.0 - xxxhdpi

May it'll be Helpful...

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is make different layout files and put it in different folders (like `layout-sw300dp`, `layout-sw400dp`, `layout-sw600dp`). These will be layouts that are to be displayed in screens with different sizes and density.

Comment: Please tell me, why on Android 1.5 and less versions all works without creating many layout files?

Answer (score 1):

[1.6 Donut added support for different screen sizes and resolutions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#DONUT):

> They [apps targeting API level 4] are assumed to support different screen densities and sizes. (Apps targeting earlier versions are assumed to only support medium density normal size screens unless otherwise indicated). They can still explicitly specify screen support either way with the supports-screens manifest tag.

So when your *target* SDK level is less than 4, you'll get a compatibility mode where `dp` and `sp` units don't really have any effect. Only when the target level is 4 or higher, are the pixels scaled accordingly.